# texlipse builder script configuration

Tags: texlipse

I need to compile my file in the following way:

```
pdflatex file.tex
bibtex book
bibtex journals
bibtex conferences
pdflatex file.tex
pdflatex file.tex
```

Of course, I can build it manually from command line, however, is there any way, how to setup TeXlipse to build it automatically in this way?

---

well, I know, how to create the script for compilation, the question is, how to force TeXlipse to use my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this question doesn't depends on the Editor TeXlipse. So I want to try to answer in a more general way.

### Script

To setup your own compilation run you can write your own script. For windows it could be a `bat` file and for Unix a shell-script. For example a simple script could be:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash         
# file mycompile
echo "My project compilation"
pdflatex file.tex
bibtex book
bibtex journals
bibtex conferences
pdflatex file.tex
pdflatex file.tex
```

Now you can configure you editor to run `mycompile`. This method isn't very flexible.

### arara

To setup the compilation run out of your main `.tex` file you can use [`arara`](http://cereda.github.com/arara/).

`arara` must be setup in your editor like `pdflatex` and then you can use in your header:

```
% arara: pdflatex 
% arara: bibtex: {inputaux: [book , journals , conferences ] }
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
```

If you don't need all compilations you can comment them by `!`. For more details have a look at the documentation: https://github.com/cereda/arara/downloads whereby the final documentation isn't finished yet.

To get the correct identifier `inputaux` the file `bibtex.yaml` can be:

```
!config
identifier: bibtex
name: BibTeX
command: 'bibtex @{expandoptions} 
                 @{inputaux == "" ? file : inputaux}.aux'
arguments:
  - identifier: expandoptions
    flag: '@{value}'
  - identifier: inputaux
    flag: '@{value}'
```

Comment: well, I know, how to create the script for compilation, the question is, how to force TeXlipse to use my script?

Answer (score 8):

You can configure TeXlipse to use a custom script through the following steps:

## Method 1: Script as part of the build process

This method will include the script as part of the build process, that is, you need to tell TeXlipse to build your project via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, then your script will be executed.

Go to `Project > Properties`:

[image: Properties]

Select the `Builders` tab and then click the `New...` button:

[image: New builder]

We need to choose which type of builder we want. Select `Program`, then click `OK`:

[image: Program]

Now, configure your script accordingly (sorry for the shameless self-promotion here):

[image: Edit configuration]

Our new tool is now listed in the `Builders` list. You can check/uncheck the builders you want to use:

[image: My tool]

Now, we just need to run it through `Project > Build all` or via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>:

[image: Build all]

We can see that the tool was correctly executed (I wrote a dummy directive to force `arara` to raise an error):

[image: Running]

Done. `:)`

## Method 2: Script as an external program

This configuration only sets your script to be manually executed through the `Run` button.

Click the `Run` button and select `External tools`:

[image: External tools]

Configure your script accordingly:

[image: Configuration]

And now our tool is available in the `Run` button:

[image: Run tool]

Hope it helps. `:)`

<sub>Both methods are project-based, so you need to replicate these steps in other projects.</sub>