# TeXlipse, bibunits, and multiple bibliographies

Tags: bibtex, subdividing, texlipse, bibunits

I am using Eclipse 4.2 with TeXlipse 1.5 (the version bundled with StatET 3.2) and MixTeX 2.9.  I have no problem using TeXlipse, bibtex, and `natbib` to produce bibliographies.  But I often want to include multiple bibliographies (i.e., lists of references) in the same document.  `natbib` isn't up to this task.  In these cases, I turn to the `bibunits` package.

The problem is that Texlipse doesn't work well with `bibunits`.  When latex (or pdflatex, etc.) is run on a document that includes `\usepackage{bib units}`, it generates an `.aux` file for each bibliography that is to be created: `bu1.aux`, `bu2.aux`, and so on.  If the bibliographies are to be produced, bibtex needs to process each of these `.aux` files:

```
bibtex bu1.aux
bibtex bu2.aux
```

and so on.  But Texlipse doesn't seem to know this.  So it doesn't, by default, direct bibtex to process those `.aux files`.  The result is that the bibliographies don't display as they should.

Here is a complete example of a document that the command-line tools (pdflatex, bibtex) handle fine but that gives Texlipse a lot of trouble.  Although it uses `bibunits`, it has only one bibliography (to keep things simple):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibunits}
  \defaultbibliography{references}
  \defaultbibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
  \begin{bibunit}
    Lorem ipsum dolor \citep{Smith_Lorem_1980}.
    \putbib
  \end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

where `references.bib` is

```
@BOOK{Smith_Lorem_1980,
  AUTHOR    = {John Smith},
  TITLE     = {Sit Amet},
  YEAR      = {1980},
  PUBLISHER = {Knopf},
}
```

(The example requires a separate `.bib` file: TeXlipse doesn't support `\thebibliography` commands.)

Is there a way to change the Texlipse configuration so that it can handle the .aux file that is generated when files like the example file are processed?  Right now, I have rigged up a workaround (configuring BibTeX as an "external tool" to process the `.aux` files), but it is clunky.

Comment: You can setup your editor for arara to simplify the compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the instructions depicted within this question [texlipse builder script configuration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60131/texlipse-builder-script-configuration) I point my external build program to a windows `bat` file.

When using windows running MikTex, I create the following script/organization.

1. In the eclipse project directory I create a `src` directory to sort all but my main tex file
2. Outside this directory with the build tools I place my main `tex` file
3. I tend to keep my references which may be common to multiple project to prevent duplication
4. The `bat` files are based on for loops and current directory variables to identify the project file to build.
5. To address the bibunits specific nature of the question I use a custom `bat` file (seen in the example below named `bibunitBuild.bat` containing `bu*.aux` in a for loop
6. A clean up script is also easy to create and include and depends on your desire to retain logs of the process or a clean working directory with no tmp files.

Contents of `bibunitBuild.bat`:

```
FOR %%B IN (bu*.aux) DO ( ECHO Will try and compile %%~dpB%%~nB with bibtex & "%MikTexPath%bibtex.exe" --include-directory="%%~dpB\..\..\References"  "%%~dpB%%~nB")
```

Contents of `xelatexCompile.bat`

```
:CheckOS
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (GOTO 32BIT) ELSE (GOTO 64BIT)

:64BIT
ECHO 64-bit compiling
SET MikTexPath=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\
GOTO END

:32BIT
ECHO 32-bit compiling
SET MikTexPath=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\
GOTO END

:END

SET TeXCompilier=xelatex.exe

FOR %%A IN (*.tex) DO (
"%MikTexPath%%TeXCompilier%" "%%~nxA" &_
call bibunitBuild.bat &_
"%MikTexPath%makeindex.exe" -s "%%~nA.ist" -t "%%~nA.glg" -o "%%~nA.gls" "%%~nA.glo" &_
"%MikTexPath%makeindex.exe" -s "%%~nA.ist" -t "%%~nA.alg" -o "%%~nA.acr" "%%~nA.acn" &_
"%MikTexPath%%TeXCompilier%" "%%~nxA" &_
"%MikTexPath%%TeXCompilier%" "%%~nxA" &_
)
```