# Setting up TeXlipse with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber, texlipse

EDITED

---

I'm trying to get biblatex to work in [TeXlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/). My current tex file is:

```
\documentclass{ut-thesis}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{thesis.bib}

\degree{Test Degree}
\department{Deparment}
\gradyear{Year}
\author{Author}
\title{UT-Thesis Class File Example}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\flushbottom

%%%%%%%%%%%%      MAIN  DOCUMENT      %%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{preliminary}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\end{preliminary}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Why?}
This is a section \cite{ID}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

With test.bib containing:

```
@Article{ID,
author = {Author},
title = {Title},
journal = {journal},
year = {2013}
}

@Article{ID2,
author = {Authors},
title = {Title 2},
journal = {Journal 2},
year = {2013}
}
```

But i keep getting the warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 37.
Please (re)run Biber on the file:   document.tex
```

I am trying to run `biber` as a manual build program with

```
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\biber.exe
Working Directory: ${workspace_loc:/Thesis/tmp}
Arguments: thesis
```

I get the following console output:

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.7
INFO - Logfile is 'thesis.blg'
INFO - Reading 'thesis.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'thesis.bib' for section 0
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/bibtex/bib/unswcover/thesis.bib'
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'ID' (section 0)
INFO - Overriding locale 'English_United States.1252' default tailoring 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting 'entry' list 'nty' keys
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'English_United States.1252'
INFO - Writing 'thesis.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'
INFO - Output to thesis.bbl
INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

This program works in Texmaker when i set it up to run

```
pdflatex > biber > pdflatex > pdflatex
```

but I want to get it working in TeXlipse.

Comment: Running `biber myfile.bcf` is enough for the command line.  As for the editor, you probably need to configure it to call `biber` instead of `bibtex`..?

Comment: Your document compiles fine, the problem seems to be, that texlipse calls biber just once. Perhaps adjusting the builder script could provide a solution. There was a thread on that topic:  [TeXlipse builder-script configuration](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60131/texlipse-builder-script-configuration); If you don’t like arara use latexmk.

Comment: When creating a builder-script what would I add into the arguments in order to run biber again? Or would that go somewhere else? I also get an error "latexmk.exe: The Perl interpreter could not be found." when I use latexmk.

Comment: See this [issue (on the project issue tracker)](http://sourceforge.net/p/texlipse/bugs/351/)

Comment: henruqie, it says that the issue was fixed and I have the newest version of texlipse (1.5.0)

Comment: Jason: please ping @henrique like this, otherwise he may not receive your call.

Comment: @henrique please see my comment above. I believe that was fixed.

Comment: There are some limitations in the way texlipse detects the biblatex backend, worth checking forthose still having issues: http://sourceforge.net/p/texlipse/discussion/451977/thread/1a984278/

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by unchecking the default LaTeX builder and creating my own `pdflatex` and `biber` builders (`pdflatex > biber > pdflatex (2) > pdflatex (final)`). I think it had to do with having a different `tmp` folder where the `.bbl` and other files were being written so I used the same directory for all builders.