# Eclipse TexLipse BibLatex configuration

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, texlipse

I'm trying to build the Bibliography of my thesis using TexLipse but unfortunately I found no configuration to get it working. Hopefully someone was able to get it working and could help me to get it working too.
[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations) there is a Q&A related to my problem, so maybe you can contribute to both questions because it lacks of the answer for TeXlipse. Thanks in advance for your time.

Here is a simplified version of my Tex file and References.bib:

**document.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{DUMMY:1}

\section{Title}

\subsection{Subtitle}

Plain text.

\subsection{Another subtitle}

More plain text.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**References.bib**

```
@BOOK{DUMMY:1,
    AUTHOR="John Doe",
    TITLE="The Book without Title",
    PUBLISHER="Dummy Publisher",
    YEAR="2100",
}
```

This is the project structure:

[image: This is the project structure]

When I save the document.tex this is what the build outputs on the console:

```
running: B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 

-interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials document.tex 
pdflatex.exe> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit)
pdflatex.exe> entering extended mode
pdflatex.exe> (document.tex
pdflatex.exe> LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
pdflatex.exe> Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
pdflatex.exe> Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty")))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.def"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xstring\xstring.tex"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-dm.def")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-compat.def")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.def")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\authoryear.bbx"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\standard.bbx"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx\authoryear.cbx")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.cfg"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\english.lbx")
pdflatex.exe> (document.aux) (document.bbl)
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> LaTeX Warning: Citation 'DUMMY:1' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 24.
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> [1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (document.aux)
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
pdflatex.exe> (biblatex)                document
pdflatex.exe> (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe>  )<B:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><B:/Pr
pdflatex.exe> ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><B:/Program Fi
pdflatex.exe> les/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
pdflatex.exe> Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 34469 bytes).
pdflatex.exe> SyncTeX written on document.synctex.gz.
pdflatex.exe> Transcript written on document.log.
running: B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\bibtex.exe document 
bibtex.exe> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit)
bibtex.exe> The top-level auxiliary file: document.aux
bibtex.exe> I found no \citation commands---while reading file document.aux
bibtex.exe> I found no \bibdata command---while reading file document.aux
bibtex.exe> I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file document.aux
bibtex.exe> (There were 3 error messages)
running: B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials document.tex 
pdflatex.exe> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit)
pdflatex.exe> entering extended mode
pdflatex.exe> (document.tex
pdflatex.exe> LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
pdflatex.exe> Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
pdflatex.exe> Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty")))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.def"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xstring\xstring.tex"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-dm.def")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-compat.def")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.def")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\authoryear.bbx"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\standard.bbx"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx\authoryear.cbx")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.cfg"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\english.lbx")
pdflatex.exe> (document.aux) (document.bbl)
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> LaTeX Warning: Citation 'DUMMY:1' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 24.
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> [1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (document.aux)
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
pdflatex.exe> (biblatex)                document
pdflatex.exe> (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe>  )<B:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><B:/Pr
pdflatex.exe> ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><B:/Program Fi
pdflatex.exe> les/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
pdflatex.exe> Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 34469 bytes).
pdflatex.exe> SyncTeX written on document.synctex.gz.
pdflatex.exe> Transcript written on document.log.
running: B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials document.tex 
pdflatex.exe> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit)
pdflatex.exe> entering extended mode
pdflatex.exe> (document.tex
pdflatex.exe> LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
pdflatex.exe> Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
pdflatex.exe> Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty")))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.def"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xstring\xstring.tex"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-dm.def")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-compat.def")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.def")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\authoryear.bbx"
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\standard.bbx"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx\authoryear.cbx")
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.cfg"))
pdflatex.exe> ("B:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\english.lbx")
pdflatex.exe> (document.aux) (document.bbl)
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> LaTeX Warning: Citation 'DUMMY:1' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 24.
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> [1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (document.aux)
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
pdflatex.exe> (biblatex)                document
pdflatex.exe> (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe>  )<B:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><B:/Pr
pdflatex.exe> ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><B:/Program Fi
pdflatex.exe> les/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
pdflatex.exe> Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 34469 bytes).
pdflatex.exe> SyncTeX written on document.synctex.gz.
pdflatex.exe> Transcript written on document.log.
running: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" document.pdf
```

and here are the Problems it generates:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Here you can find a example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)). I hope it will help.

Comment: The problem is that TeXlipse runs BibTeX and not Biber. I read somewhere that TeXlipse had problems to recognise that it had to run Biber if `backend=biber` was the first option, so try `\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}`

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127024/35864 Have a look at http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/biblatex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeXlipse uses a document parser to automatically determine whether to run BibTeX or Biber from the document source.

As documented on the web (https://sourceforge.net/p/texlipse/discussion/451977/thread/1a984278/#c309), the parser is a bit fussy when it comes to recognising that Biber needs to be run.

Apparently, `backend=biber` cannot contain any spaces around the `=`. Furthermore, in multi-line `\usepackage` lines `backend=biber` can't be on the first line.

So you will have to load `biblatex` as follows

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

or (after a line break)

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
]{biblatex}
```

TeXlipse development has been picked up by Eclipse Foundation, see http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/, http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/science.texlipse and https://github.com/eclipse/texlipse. Maybe the shortcomings of the parser are addressed in future releases.